решение проблемы затухающего градиента
Есть нейросеть с 1 скрытым слоем (функция активации - сигмоида), на выходе входного слоя функция активации тоже сигмоида. Оптимайзер - Adam, функция ошибки - MSEloss. Входных данных - 3, выходной - 1. Ошибка не падает ниже 0.2500, значение всегда около 0.5008. Перепробовал множество комбинаций нейронов и функций активации, ничего не помогает.

Можно два скрытых слоя сделать

Ничего не меняется ни с 1, ни с 3-мя скрытыми слоями. Ошибка и выходные значения одни и те-же.

Ну, вроде-как разобрался. Поделюсь опытом: ошибка была достаточно глупая НИКОГА НЕ ДОПУСКАТЕ ОТРИЦАТЕЛЬНЫЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ ВО ВХОДНЫХ ДАННЫХ. Я по наивности думал, что если нормализовать данные от -1 до 1 до всё будет в норме, но нет.
